# Modification package.json in node_modules folder

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, app-store, node-modules

I have a react native project with typescript and expo, throughout the project I have used different external dependencies and those dependencies used native node js modules (which are not by default in react native), one of these solutions I had to **modify a package.json** from a folder within node_modules, change a "main" field which came from an entry point of a folder and the index.js and change it to another folder from there and the index.js (because That's how they told me to do it), now, we plan to upload the project to Playstore and Apple and build it to run it on several devices to test it before, now, I have the following doubts and questions:

- I modified a package.json inside node_modules folders. Would there be a problem with that when building the app? I mean, would it really work with that modification I made? Since if you ignore that modification at the end, a dependency that I have does not work.
- When I upload it to Apple and the Play Store (investigating how to do this, I think it is remote to upload the app), does it not open any kind of problem with the same thing?

I want to assume that there would be no problem uploading to the stores or executing the corresponding builds, but anyway, is there any way to be sure of this change in that package? Because in the future this project other developers will have access to the repository and it would be difficult be modifying that folder when they want to install all the dependencies.